# MySQL tables in Collation latin1_swedish_ci can I just change without impacting PHP code?

Tags: php, mysql, collation

I setup a MySQL table using Collation latin1_swedish_ci.
I have coded my PHP scripts in the UTF-8 character-set. It all worked out well until I discovered that a person entered their first name with a non-swedish character.
The name **Helén** looked strange in the database but looked OK on the webpages.

My question is, can I simply change the Collation of my table from latin1_swedish_ci to UTF-8?

Will it actually cause any problems?

Comment: its the character set not the collation at issue here

Comment: i think you should put this exactly after you connected to your database in your php code: mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8'); , but as i'm not sure i didn't post it as an answer

Comment: The `latin1` encoding can perfectly represent "é", that's not the issue. The issue is the *connection encoding.* [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: @deceze Ok. So does this mean I do not actually do anything about it or is there some change I need to do?

Comment: You need to fix the connection encoding as outlined in the linked-to sites above. The database encoding is fine; as long as you only need to store "western" characters the latin1 encoding can store. If you need to store other characters too, you should go with UTF-8. [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by adding

```
$db->set_charset("utf8"); // MySQL
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); // Set PHP encoding
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); // Prevent incorrect encoding in Browser
```

at the top and escaping every parameter using

```
$param=$db->escape_string($param);
```

Then MySQL/PHP will handle everything which is encoding-related for you. When you did this, all your stuff will be in UTF-8.

Your problem with the name is probably related to the header() command, that means that the browser choooses another charset than PHP. You can fix your data by doing that:

```
$data=utf8_encode($data);
```

If that produces bad results, try this one:

```
$data=utf8_decode($data);
```

After that everything should look fine.

If you want to make UTF8 the default charset, consider adding the following to my.cnf in [mysqld]:

```
# Set UTF-8 as standard
collation-server = utf8mb4_general_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-server = utf8mb4
```

That's what I did, I haven't had any issues since a year of development with all what I mentioned in this post.

Comment: `mb_internal_encoding` is only relevant for the mb_ functions, nothing else. `utf8_encode` and `_decode` are usually completely unnecessary and *encoding conversions* are best handled elsewhere. PHP never handles anything encoding related "for you". You just have to get it right at every interface between different systems. Sorry, your post is mostly a random accumulation of encoding related functions without really explaining what's happening or what needs to happen.